# How can I Integrate Python Scripts into a MERN stack

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I am thinking of adding python scripts for some data analysis but I am using a MERN stack for my application.

An example of what I am thinking-

My python script will do some data analysis when an endpoint is being called.
../api/dopythonhere and return a JSON object

What would be the best/efficient way to implement python with a MERN stack?

Answer (score 0):

So as far as I understood you have currently an API or full-build functional application made in or partially coded in Python (unknown stack). Therefore you want to migrate this to MERN Stack or call the Python API via your MERN application. There are several things you can do to work with this, but those two might be the cleanest:

- Completely migrate and integrate your Python app into your Node.js & Express app and forget about the Python source code.
- If it's not already done, make the Python app a functional web API. Therefore you can call it either from the Node API using libraries like Axios or similar (so in your API you can modify the data structure and only send to the front what you need), or you can also call the Python API directly via React front-end, using web development vanilla APIs or any libraries you want.